# Does IBM Worklight provide socket programming API's for Android, iOS, Windows Phones?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, ibm-mobilefirst

I have to open multiple threads to a socket/port for an Andriod/iOS app. Does IBM Worklight provide socket programming API's for Android, iOS, Windows Phones ? Or what would a best cross platform approach by which we could achieve this using Worklight framework. !!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Such API is not available via the Worklight framework.

If this is not possible via good o' JavaScript, the only other alternative is to use native code, which means [implementing a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid) (one per required environment -- not sure about Windows Phone here in this context).